# Array gets overwritten on puppeteer when it scrapes another page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape multiple pages at once, but I can't get data from the first **manufacturers** element (makita), it gets info I need, I checked on browser's console, however I really don't know how to access (and store it) before gets overwritten, example:

It scrapes 11 products from "www.lojadomecanico.com.br/**makita**/F/C/" and writes on data[0-10], then goes to the second website "www.lojadomecanico.com.br/**vonder**/F/C/", gets another 11 products, but instead of writing on data[11-21], it overwrites data[0-10], so I end up only with **vonder** products scraped

Sorry if it's a dumb question, I've spent the whole morning (14:55 currently here (UTC+3) trying to find an answer, I think I've understood why it's getting overwritten, but I couldn't make it work, I've erased all useless things I've tried, so the code is working.

What I want is to be able to save all data it scrapes, all **makita**, **vonder** and future manufacturers products, without losing any data.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
let manufacturers = ['makita', 'vonder']
let lastpage = [2, 2]
var scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    for (let i = 0; i < manufacturers.length; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    await page.goto('https://www.lojadomecanico.com.br/'+manufacturers[i]+'/F/C/');

    var results = []; // variable to hold collection of all book titles and prices
    var lastPageNumber = lastpage[i]; // this is hardcoded last catalogue page, you can set it dinamically if you wish
    // defined simple loop to iterate over number of catalogue pages
    for (let index = 1; index < lastPageNumber; index++) {
        // wait 1 sec for page load
        await page.waitFor(1000);
        // call and wait extractedEvaluateCall and concatenate results every iteration.
        // You can use results.push, but will get collection of collections at the end of iteration
        results = results.concat(await extractedEvaluateCall(page));
        // this is where next button on page clicked to jump to another page
        if (index < lastPageNumber - 1) {
            // no next button on last page
            await page.click('#center_column > div.sortPagiBar.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.top10 > div > nav > ul > li:last-child > a');
        }
    }
}
    // browser.close();
    return results;
};

async function extractedEvaluateCall(page) {
    // just extracted same exact logic in separate function
    // this function should use async keyword in order to work and take page as argument
    // for (let u = 0; u < 2; u++) {
    return page.evaluate(() => {
        var data = [];
        var selector = document.querySelectorAll('#view-product-list > ul.row.product-list.grid > li')
        for (var element of selector) {
            const rb = element.querySelector('.right-block')
            day = new Date()
            const scrape_date = day.getDate() + '/' + (day.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + day.getFullYear();
            var name = rb.querySelector('h2 > a').getAttribute('title')
            var price = rb.querySelector('.content_price > .price.product-price').innerHTML
            price = price.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "")
            price = parseFloat(price)
            price = price / 100
            var model = rb.querySelector('h2 > a > span').innerHTML
            data.push({ scrape_date, name, price, model });
            }
        return data
    })
// }
}

scrape().then((value) => {
    let fileContent = JSON.stringify(value);
    fs.writeFileSync('LojadoMecanico.txt', fileContent);
    console.log('Items scraped: ' + value.length);
    // console.dir(value, {depth: null, colors: true, maxArrayLength: null});
    console.table(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare `var results = [];` before the `for (let i = 0; i < manufacturers.length; i++) {`, otherwise `results` is redefined in each iteration.

And try not to use `var` at all to avoid these situations with scope, use `let` and `const` only.